# AsyncStorage.removeItem('my_token'); returns null

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

Below is my code, whenever I try to logout by clicking `onButtonPress` it returns `err : null`, and my token is not removed from local storage. Please help me solve this.

```
onButtonPress = async () => {
    try {
        await AsyncStorage.removeItem('id_token', err =>
            console.log('error : ' + err)
        );
        console.log('logged out!');
        this.props.navigation.navigate('main');
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('AsyncStorage error: ' + error.message);
    }
};
```

Comment: Why are you passing a callback function?

Comment: any disadvantage of using that callback function? Please solve my issue and suggest the appropriate edits. @vijayst

Comment: when you are using await, you are anyway waiting for the promise to return the result. And if it errors out, the catch part of the promise will be executed. In this case, since you are using async / await, the catch block will be executed. There is no need to pass a callback.

Comment: And in your case, err = null means that the function executed well.

Comment: Okay, thanks for clearing my doubt. But even after removing that unnecessary call back function my token remains in storage. So please can you elaborate where I'm doing any mistake?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
async removeKey() {
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.removeItem('id_token');
      this.props.navigation.navigate('main');
        } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error resetting data" + error);
    }
  }
```

Comment: "try this" is a bit too short as an answer. It would be more useful if you would explain what was wrong with the Asker's code and why/how your version fixes it.